# Opening a bar on top of the page with firefox sdk

Tags: firefox, sdk, firefox-addon, panel

I am making a firefox pluggin and I want to open a "topbar" on a few websites. Realy, it would be a few informations about the curent page a link back to my own website. What would be te best way to do that ?

My first idea was to use content script, but that seems to be a very bad practice. I also read about panels, here are my questions :

- How can I add my pannel just under the adressbar ?
- How can I only open in it on the website I need ?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using content script is completely fine.
It is modern, simple, less-code, more compatible way 
to add top-panel to some web pages. 
Also, code of content script is not injected to the web page, it just uses the dom and context; page script has no access (if you do not provide it explicit) to content script.

The only possible disadvantage is that panel would not look like native part of the browser.

If I convienced you to use content script:

1. The module you really need in your plugin [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-23/modules/sdk/page-mod.html)
2. Using [Add-on Builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/) you make have your plugin in a day